# How to preserve minted's foreground color while highlighting code sections with \colorbox

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting, colorbox

I'm currently working on highlighting specific sections of code snippets in my LaTeX document. To achieve this, I followed the example provided in the documentation for the `minted` package, specifically the section that explains the `escapeinside` option. However, I've encountered an issue where using `\colorbox` to highlight sections of code seems to overwrite the foreground color that was applied by minted.

For instance, using

```tex
\mintinline{c}$int foo(int x) {$
```

I get

[image: Generate snippet without using escapeinside]

While using

```tex
\mintinline[escapeinside=||]{c}$int foo(|\colorbox{lightgray}{int x}|) {$
```

I get

[image]

Is there a way to preserve the original foreground color highlighted by `minted` while applying a background color to specific code sections using `\colorbox`?